# Type ambiguity with numbers

Tags: haskell, types

I ran across something I find curious while playing around with the Haskell interactive prompt (ghci). The following code run under ghci 7.0.4

```
[minBound..1]
```

throws the following exception:

```
<interactive>:1:12:
    Ambiguous type variable `t0' in the constraints:
      (Num t0) arising from the literal `1' at <interactive>:1:12
      (Enum t0) arising from the arithmetic sequence `minBound .. 1'
                at <interactive>:1:1-13
      (Bounded t0) arising from a use of `minBound'
                   at <interactive>:1:2-9
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    In the expression: 1
    In the expression: [minBound .. 1]
    In an equation for `it': it = [minBound .. 1]
```

I know that writing the above as [minBound..1 :: Int] would make it clear that '1' here is meant to be an **Int**, but my question is, where does the ambiguity lie? '1' could be interpreted as **Int**, **Integer**, **Float** or **Double**, but none of these except **Int** belong to the ***Bounded*** class. So is there another class that literal 1 could masquerade as? If not, then what?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per the [defaulting rules](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-790004.3.4), a constrained type variable is tried to be resolved by defaulting, if

- all constraints have the form `C a`; `a` doesn't appear as an argument to a type constructor in the constraint, and
- at least one of the classes involved is a numeric class,and
- all of the classes are defined in the Prelude or the standard libraries.

The inferred type of the expression `[minBound .. 1]` is

```
[minBound .. 1] :: (Num a, Enum a, Bounded a) => [a]
```

so the defaulting rules apply. But for defaulting, only types listed in the *default declaration* of the module are considered - in the absence of a default declaration, the *default default* of `(Integer, Double)` is assumed, i.e. to resolve a constrained ambiguous type variable, first `Integer` is tried, and if that doesn't satisfy all constraints, `Double` is tried. If that doesn't satisfy all constraints either, defaulting fails and the compilation fails with an `ambiguous type variable` error¹.

In the case at hand, neither `Integer` nor `Double` satisfy the `Bounded` constraint, so defaulting fails.

¹ In ghci, or with the `ExtendedDefaultRules` extension enabled, defaulting is also attempted if no numeric class is among the constraints but `Show` is, and the default default is extended by `()`.

Comment: Good answer, thanks; I was making assumptions about how Haskell's type inference works, now I know better